# How to check if variable contains valid UTF-8 string without any control characters?

Tags: bash, string

How can I check in bash whether a variable contains a valid UTF-8 string without any special control characters (such as newline or backspace or carriage return etc.)?

Answer (score 12):

Provided the locale uses UTF-8 as its character encoding (check with `locale charmap`):

```
[[ $string =~ ^[^[:cntrl:]]*$ ]]
```

should work except that at least on GNU systems, it fails to reject strings that contain the UTF-8 encoding of characters with code points above 0x110000 (which are [no longer valid in the current definition of UTF-8 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3)). That's down to the system's regexp library `bash` uses to do pattern matching.

That's the same for GNU `expr` and:

```
expr " $string" : ' [^[:cntrl:]]*$' > /dev/null
```

Here, you may want to switch to `zsh` where, in UTF-8 locales,

```bsh
set -o extendedglob
[[ $string = [' '-$'\ud7fff'$'\ue000'-$'\U10FFFF']# && $string != *[[:cntrl:]]* ]]
```

should work consistently regardless of the system (at least for the matching of valid characters; you might find variations between systems for which character is classified as `[:cntrl:]`).

In zsh glob patterns, character ranges in multibyte character locales are based on the the wide character value of the character, which in UTF-8 is invariably the Unicode code point. Bytes that don't form part of valid characters are assigned wchar_t values in the 0xDC80..0xDCFF range in the second part of the 0xD800..0xDFFF UTF16 surrogate pairs which are not characters (a [common approach sanctioned by Unicode to be able to handle arbitrary sequences of bytes](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#EnablingLosslessConversion)).

[Character range handling in bash glob patterns is mostly random](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00054.html), so can't be used here.

You may also want to consider what to do with [non-characters](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#noncharacters), [private use characters](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#private_use), characters that are not currently assigned in the version of Unicode your system is working with. The notion of *control* character is also quite fuzzy when it comes to Unicode. Are the U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE character, the U+FEFF BOM character, the [*tag* characters](https://www.unicode.org/faq/languagetagging.html) for instance *control* characters?

Comment: does `LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8` at the start of the script ensure that the loale is set to UTF-8? Also these not-rejected codepoints abover  0x110000 are never ccontrol characters, or are they?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann, only on systems that have such a locale and if `$LC_ALL` is not otherwise also set. Setting `LC_CTYPE` without also setting the other `LC_*` variables is not always well supported. Note that unless you export that variable, it will not affect commands that are *executed* (as opposed to those that are internal to the shell. It will not affect `expr` for instance above). Several systems now ship a `C.UTF-8` locale which may be a better option (`export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`, possibly only set locally to a function for instance).

Comment: Those codepoints above 0x110000 are not valid. How the bytes that form the  would-be-UTF-8-encoding of those codepoints are interpreted by applications is unspecified and will vary between applications as you're dealing with invalid text.

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann: If you encounter them treat them as private use characters or reject the bytestream. If they become valid, having previously treated them as private use should be correct.

Comment: @Joshua, depends why the OP wants to detect those. For instance, a `python3` script (at least with python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu) won't even start if it has a byte sequence that is the encoding of code points over 0x110000 in its arguments.